# Bool property is set to true without being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, boolean

I am making an web application for articles reading.

I have bool property which is set to true if the specific `Edit` Button is clicked, there is also a `Save` Button which is clicked after filling user information on `TextBoxes` and other controls. Whenever I run my application and fills information, it runs fine but after 4 or 5 runs (re-starting the application) it gives an Exception error upon clicking `Save` Button:
`Input string was not in a correct format` which is due to filling `TextBoxes` with Null( firstly, Null is converted into Int).

My problem is that bool property (`Managment.IsEditing`) is set to true without any reason ( `Edit` Button should be pressed to  set bool to true). Why and how is set to true automatically as its code is only being called in `EditButton_Click` Event?

**Here is a code**

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(EditorList.SelectedIndex > -1) //Just to ensure that Item is selected from ListBox
    {   
        //editor is the poco  , EditorManager is the editor table manager
        editor = EditorManager.GetEditorInfo(EditorList.SelectedValue);

        NameTextBox.Text = editor.Name;
        EmailTextBox1.Text = editor.Email;
        PasswordTextBox.Text = editor.Password;
        EditorIDTextBox.Text = editor.Editor_ID.ToString();

        for (int index = 0; index < RoleCheckBoxList.Items.Count; index++)
        {
          RoleCheckBoxList.Items[index].Selected = editor.RoleList[index];
        }

        Managment.IsEditing = true; //This flag is responsible for telling "SaveButtton" that editor would be updated. 
        DeleteButton.Enabled = true;
        ResultLabel.Text = "";
    }

    else
        ResultLabel.Text = "Select Editor from list first";

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Managment.IsEditing == false) //it makes sure that new editor is being saved
    {
        editor.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
        string email = EmailTextBox1.Text;
        editor.Email = email.ToLower();
        editor.Password = PasswordTextBox.Text;

        if(EditorManager.IsEditorValid(editor.Email))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < RoleCheckBoxList.Items.Count; index++)
            {
              editor.RoleList[index] = RoleCheckBoxList.Items[index].Selected;
            }

            EditorManager.Save(editor);
            ResultLabel.Text = editor.DataUploadMessage;            
        }

        else
            ResultLabel.Text = "Editor with the same Email can't be add!";

        FillEditorList();
    }

    else if(Managment.IsEditing == true) //it determines that existing editor is being updated and problem is that Managment.IsEditing is turned on without being called.
    {
        editor.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
        string email = EmailTextBox1.Text;
        editor.Email = email.ToLower();
        editor.Password = PasswordTextBox.Text;
        editor.Editor_ID = Convert.ToInt32(EditorIDTextBox.Text);// Error occurs at this line

        for (int index = 0; index < RoleCheckBoxList.Items.Count; index++)
        {
          editor.RoleList[index] = RoleCheckBoxList.Items[index].Selected;
        }

        EditorManager.Edit(editor);

        ResultLabel.Text = editor.DataUploadMessage;
        Managment.IsEditing = false;
        FillEditorList();            
    }
    ClearFields(Form.Controls);
}
```

**Exception occurs on that line:**

```
editor.Editor_ID = Convert.ToInt32(EditorIDTextBox.Text);
```

and sorry for any inconvenience dear fellows

Comment: please give us the code of the issue.

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: Have investigated on why your `textBoxes` get null ?

Comment: Why beginners are downvoted ,give them some time to learn the SO environment !

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't contain a bool property.

Comment: @MrLister `Managment.IsEditing` is the bool property

Comment: The computer isn't just screwing with you, there are only 2 possibilities here: Either you have code somewhere causing the click of that button (a client side script simulating the click maybe?) or there is a place in your code where you are calling the EditButton_Click method (or setting the property).

Comment: @JoelEtherton I have pasted all the code, 1) No client side .js 2) EditButton_Click() not called anywhere except on the event for which it is made

Comment: What do you mean by "after 4 or 5 runs"? What is a run? Is a run clicking edit and then save? Or is a run actually starting the application?

Comment: @comecme A run actually re-starting the application

Answer (score 1):

When the exception occurs on the indicated line, the line that resets your flag won't be run. The page will then likely be in an invalid state.

Try fixing/handling the error and clean up properly, and the problem might go away.

Comment: I use Try catch to handle the exception and it don't let my application to crash but it didn't solve my problem. As you sad that the line for resetting the flag won't be run... So my problem is that why this flag is turned to true without being called. ( this flag is turned true in "EditButoon_Click" Event)

Comment: I edit my post very carefully and tried my best to explain. I request to read it again. Thanks very much!